# Insert hyperlink using CSS Id and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink

I am trying to do just as the title says. I have a css id that I am trying to add a clickable link to.

Any help is appreciated thank you

I have a class id for an element and I would like to create a hyperlink using jquery that takes you to an external site when you click on the element

I right click inspect element using google chrome and I am selecting the image I would like to associate the link with. when I hit copy css path I get: `#post-1897 > figure > img`

there is no div class and no text because this is an image

here is the html

```
<article itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" id="post-1897" class="post-1897 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry post clearfix portfolio-post">



    <figure class="post-image ">

  <img src="http://imgsrcurl" alt="Paddle House Outfitters" width="250" height="250">                   </figure>


</article>
```

Comment: And what it says in the title makes no sense, so that's not helping at all !

Comment: what have you tried?  what does your code look like?  help us, help you!   Is there something wrong with giving an id to a regular hyperlink?

Comment: @adeneo - ah you beat me to it:D

Comment: $("<selector>").append('<a href="someUrl">Clickable</a>");

Comment: no i have tried this already and it did not work: `$("#cssidname").append("<a href='http://externallink.com'></a>");`

Comment: please post your html.

Comment: You are not giving your anchor tag any text to display.  Have you inspected element and verified it did or did not add the html?  if you mean to add a "clickable link" then this should be working.  If you intend to make the element navigate on click then try mrkou's answer :)

Comment: @ IrishGeek82 i don't want text to display because it is an image and already has alt text

Comment: For the future what is the proper way to word my question? I don't understand how my title makes no sense at all

Comment: One thing important to realize is that an id attribute is not a CSS Id.  What sprang to my mind when you mentioned that was a class as a selector $(".someCSSClassName").  Second, you didn't mention that what you were actually trying to do was make an image a clickable link.  You should also include code to demonstrate what it is you are trying to accomplish.  This helps us all to know what you have already tried.  As far as the title, something more like "How can I make an element a clickable link using JQuery" may/may not have been more clear.

Comment: I thought css id would refer to the css id selector- thanks for clairifying. I am also trying to use another css id attribute (which is not an image) to do the same thing therefore the image part of the question should not matter? thank you again

Comment: @ravens: when commenting on an answer to say "it doesn't work" please take a moment to explain where/how it fails, what it does wrong, whether you have any errors reported in your JavaScript console. Because without that information there's no way anyone can correct it to make it work for you. You very nearly 350 rep (as I write) you should know how to ask a question with clarity and precision.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$("#post-1897 > figure > img").click(function(){
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
});
```

This will redirect the page to google if you click on the selected element(s).

Or if you want to change the link of an a tag:

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: the first suggestion you gave did not work. I currently have no a tag but I am trying to add one

Answer (score 0):

This makes the image in question an actual hyperlink:

```
$('#post-1897 > figure > img').wrap('<a href="http://externallink.com"></a>');
```

But I suggest using a click event instead:

```
$('#post-1897 > figure > img').on('click', function() {
    window.location.href = "http://externallink.com"
}).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Comment: I used your exact markup with this code and it works for me. Hm.